# issue using "count++" : the first time, it repeats "0"

Tags: objective-c, button, uibutton

I had a little question :
I tried to add a +1 to a NSString. The first time I push the button `muButton`, it does not add a +1, but repeats the "0" from the beginning. However, the second push and subsequent pushes to `muButton` does increment properly. Do you know what could fix this? Here's my code :

> ```
>  - (IBAction)muButton {  
>  if(count >= 999) return;  
>  NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", count++];
> result.text = numValue;
> [numValue release];
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> - (void)viewDidLoad {  
> result.text = @"0";  
> [super viewDidLoad];
> ```
>
> }

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if `count == 0`

then `count++ == 0`

`++count == 1`

Thats what happens when you use the `++` before the parameter as opposed to after.

```
c = 0
1 + (++c) == 2
BUT
1 + (c++) == 1
c == 1 AFTERWARDS in both cases
```

When you use a pre-increment the `++` happens immediately as opposed to if you use a post-increment when it happens after the operations on the parameter take place.

Answer (score 3):

```
int var = count++;
```

is equal to :

```
int var = count;
count = count + 1;
```

maybe you want to use this :

```
int var = ++count;
```

is equal to :

```
count = count + 1;
int var = count;
```